# about the Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

In Matlab GUI, I wanna to have to plot: A*sin(x). A is the amplitude. I created a axes,a push buttton, and two edit texts, one is "Amplitude", then other one the the "A" that user will input.
In the coding part, I don't know what to do.Here's the codes I did so far.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
plot(sin(0:.1:10))

function input_ampli_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

function input_ampli_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

input = str2num(get(hObject,'String')); 

if (isempty(input))
    set(hObject,'String','0')
end

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

Comment: You have a complex homework task and let us do it for you, am I right? Question for question... That's the code your professor gave you, and you didn't show any effort. Hint: remove at least the hints. No offense, I'm sorry if my assumption is wrong. But homework questions and "Please give me the code" is not really welcomed here. Always show some own effort. And off-topic: your prof will know this site, it may won't help, if you're registered with your real name ;)

Comment: LOL, thanks for your good advise,sounds good. This is not a homework. And I have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Matlab where to plot your data, in your case it's in the axes.

The input_ampli_Callback and input_ampli_CreateFcn you showed will unlikely be used for your specific purpose. You basically just need to get the amplitude from the user using something like this:

```
A = str2num(get(handles.input_ampli,'String'));
```

and then plot the function. So everything can take place in the pushbutton callback. Your code would thus look like this:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

A = str2num(get(handles.input_ampli,'String'));

axes(handles.axes1) % This is the handles of the axes object. The name might be different. This is used to tell the GUI to make this axes the current axes, so stuff will be displayed in it.

plot(A*sin(0:.1:10)); Plot your function!
```

Of course you could add other text boxes in the GUI to let the user choose the range to plot, but the principle is the same. Hope that helps get you started!

**EDIT:** Here is the code for a simple programmatic GUI which you can customize and play around with to see how it works. It does not use guide but the principles are the same. I use global variables to easily share data between different functions (callbacks). Hope that helps too.

```
function PlotSin(~)

global ha hPlotSin htext hAmp
%  Create and then hide the GUI as it is being constructed.
f = figure('Visible','off','Position',[360,500,450,285]);

ha = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[50,60,200,185]);

% Create pushbutton
hPlotSin = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Plot',...
    'Position',[315,220,70,25],...
    'Callback',{@Plotbutton_Callback});
% Create text box
htext = uicontrol('Style','text','String','Enter amplitude',...
    'Position',[325,90,60,30]);

% Create edit box to let the user enter an amplitude 
hAmp = uicontrol('Style','Edit','String','',...
    'Position',[325,50,60,30]);

% Assign the GUI a name to appear in the window title.
set(f,'Name','Simple GUI')
% Move the GUI to the center of the screen.
movegui(f,'center')
% Make the GUI visible.
set(f,'Visible','on');


end

% This is the pushbutton callback.
function Plotbutton_Callback(source,eventdata)
global ha hPlotSin htext hAmp

A = str2num(get(hAmp,'String')); % Get the amplitude

x = 0:0.1:10; % Define x...
axes(ha) % Make the axes the current axes so the function is plot in it.

plot(x,A*sin(x)) % Plot the data

end
```